# Using the MongoDB runCommand method

Tags: java, mongodb

How to use MongoDB `runCommand` method?

I am using `db.col.runCommand("text",{search:"searchword"})` to do full text search from MongoDB console. But I want to use this command in Java, can any one suggest me how to use this in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
DBObject searchCmd = new BasicDBObject();
searchCmd.put("text", collection); // the name of the collection (string)
searchCmd.put("search", query); // the term to search for (string)
CommandResult commandResult = db.command(searchCmd);
```

Comment: i'm getting this error "can't serialize class com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection" for above code

Comment: can you post some code? For which line? Do you pass the collection name as a string or as some kind of other object?

Comment: i'm getting error at this line CommandResult commandResult = db.command(searchCmd);

Comment: My code....DBCollection col = db.getCollection("poc");DBObject searchCmd = new BasicDBObject();                    
searchCmd.put("text", col);                                          
searchCmd.put("search", "searchword");                                 
CommandResult commandResult = db.command(searchCmd);
System.out.println(commandResult);

Comment: Thanks, i have changed my code its working now but i have created text indexes for two fields. so my code is showing this err msg "errmsg" : "too many text index for: soft.poc, how to do full text search on two indexed fields, please suggest me

Comment: well, that is another question, so please consider accepting the answer. However, it seems to be a limitation of mongo. Maybe there is a workaround. Take a look here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8127?focusedCommentId=309176&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-309176